# TypeScript file is not a module

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm beginner with TypeScript, and I have one very simple problem.
I'm trying to import file, so I could import interface. For example:

Parent:

```
import { User } from "@/Users";
    
export interface Gift {
  id: number;
  user: User;
  created_at: Date,
  updated_at: Date
}
```

Child (User.ts):

```
export interface User {
    id: string;
    first_name: string,
    last_name: string,
    email: string,
    created_at: string,
    updated_at: string
}
```

So it's giving error

> File 'somepathhere/Users.ts' is not a module

In my case, Users.ts has only this interface, and nothing else, but parent component has some functions, but it's using User interface only this time.

Comment: Your import references `Users` but the file name is `User` (singular)

Comment: the import looks strange: did you mean `./user`?

Comment: It's not about file name, it's actually correct in code

Comment: Well it depends what pathname the actual error references, most likely that will give us a clue as to what exactly is going wrong

Answer (score 1):

The import statement should be `import {User} from './User'`